# Creating an arrayof Object from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object which contains email objects and their properties.
I am interested in the mime property () and I can access it using array[index].subtype.
I want to create a new array of (MIME) objects that contains only the mime and count.

```
var mimeType = []
var arr = {"object with emails"}.

    arr.forEach(function(elem, index, array){
     if(mimeType.indexOf(array[index].subtype == -1)){
                            mimeType.push({mime: array[index].subtype,    `count:1});
    }
else{
mimeType[count] = count+1;
}
```

It print all the mime, with repetition

Comment: my intention is to get somethign like this:mimeType[{mime:pdf, count:1},{mime:doc, count:2}]

Comment: you may give us some examples .

Comment: Too much syntax error. Please post code that is at least kinda working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? :

```
var tmp = {};
var arr = [{ subtype: 'pdf' }, { subtype: 'doc' }, { subtype: 'pdf' }, { subtype: 'pdf' }];

arr.forEach(function(elem, index, array){
    if(tmp[elem.subtype] === undefined){
        tmp[elem.subtype] = 1;
    }
    else {
        tmp[elem.subtype]++;
    }
});

var mimeType = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(tmp).map(function(e) { return { mime: e, count: tmp[e] }});
```

Result of mimeType =

```
[{mime:"pdf",count:3},{mime:"doc",count:1}]
```

Comment: exactly!! Thanks a ton!! :)